# Why can a network be replaced by an equivalent network according to this definition of equivalence?

Tags: electric-circuits

My textbook's definition for equivalence of two electrical networks:

"Two networks are said to be equivalent at a pair of terminals if the voltage current relationships for the two networks are identical at these terminals."

For example- equivalent resistance in linear circuits.

What I don't understand is how by that definition, given any circuit, I could replace any network of that circuit at a pair of terminals by an equivalent network, and there wouldn't be any "difference": the solution of the circuit would stay the same.

Is there a rigorous proof for this?

Comment: Duplicate?  [Proof of Thevenin and Norton theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110498/9887)

Answer (score 1):

A linear electrical network has two sets of dynamical variables: voltages and currents. If it is a two-terminal system then at the terminal has exactly two variables, a current variable and a voltage variable. To the outside what matters is this V-I relationship defined for all times. If there is another two-terminal thingy that has the same V-I relationship then to the outside they look the same for all measurable lumped element linear EM quantities.

Comment: I understand that they "look the same"- as in- given the same current there would be the same voltage across the terminals(and vice versa) , but how is that enough to state that the solution for the outside circuit wouldn't change by replacing between the two? maybe one of the networks would have a different voltage across its terminals, thus changing  the solution for the rest of the circuit?

Comment: I emphasized above that the system is *linear* and *lumped element* so every *physical* manifestation is the relationship between current in an idealized wire and voltage between idealized points. With those assumptions there is just nothing else. These assumptions may be invalid as you increase the operating frequency and one cannot assume that network is lumped element anymore, or the voltage and/or current are so high that the network is behaving in a non-linear fashion; then the "replacement" with an equivalent circuit does not hold anymore.